# Error al hacer query update a Mysql desde Express JS

Tags: mysql, nodejs, base-de-datos, express, backend

tengo un problema, intento hacer un crud básico utilizando nodeJS con los módulos de expressJS y express-myconnection, en la sección de controllers de mi proyecto generé mi función "update", la cual ejecuta una query update en mi Base de datos, según mi consola de comando la función update se ejecutó sin problemas pero el dato no se modifica.

*Terminal de comando*

```
GET /update/t99999 304 4.264 ms - -
POST /update/t99999 302 16.860 ms - 46
```

Sospecho que mi error debe estar cuando construyo la función update dentro de mi controller, adjunto código.

*archivo controller.js*

```
controller.update = (req, res) => {
  const { nro_matricula } = req.params;
  const newMatriculado = req.body;
  req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
  conn.query('UPDATE matriculado set ? WHERE nro_matricula = ?', [newMatriculado, nro_matricula], (err, filas) => {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que el error se encuentra en la siguiente linea:

```
conn.query('UPDATE matriculado set ? WHERE nro_matricula = ?', [newMatriculado, nro_matricula], (err, filas)...
```

La consulta debería ser:

```
conn.query('UPDATE matriculado set columnToUpdate = ? WHERE nro_matricula = ?', [newMatriculado, nro_matricula], (err, filas) ...
```

Comment: Saludos Ivan, gracias por responder, de igual manera seteando en Mysql la columna que quiero editar no se guarda, no tiene ningun error, pero no se edita, quiza mi error debe estar en las vistas..... voy a seguir buscando

Comment: Saludos Ivan, luego de buscar documentación Mysql mas orientada a la query UPDATE, logre hacer que mi código funcionara cambiando esa linea por la siguiente:

`UPDATE matriculado set ? WHERE nro_matricula = ?`

Donde ahora si toma la variable que yo le paso en "*newMatriculado*", ademas en el campo de vistas tenía los nombres mal colocados, en el input donde tomaba el nro_matricula se tomaba el nombre, eso también interfería con el funcionamiento del código, un saludo y gracias por responder.

Comment: Me alegra que vayas aprendiendo y es un placer ayudar